# Node position adjusting with math

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, nodes, circuitikz

It's been a while and I'm getting back into circuitikz. I'm trying to make a simple block diagram, here is my code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm,>=latex']
\node [input] at (0,0) (input) {R(s)} node[above] {$R(s)$} ; 
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node[block, right of=input] (k) {$k$};
\node[block, right of=k] (comp) {$C(s)$};
\node[block, right of=comp] (plant) {$\hat{G(s)}$};
\node [output, right of=plant] (output) {};
\node [above of=plant] (dist) {$D(s)$};
\draw[->] (input) -- (sum);
\draw[->] (sum) -- (k);
\draw[->] (k) -- (comp);
\draw[->] (comp) -- (plant);
\draw[->] (plant) -- (output) node[above] {$\hat{Y(s)}$};
\draw[->] (plant) -| ++(2,-1) -| (sum) node[pos=.9, left] {$-$};
\draw[->] (dist) -- (plant);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm looking more specificatlly at the line

```
\node [above of=plant] (dist) {$D(s)$};
```

I can't remember how I used to do it, but I could use math mode to adjust the positioning. It may have been something along the lines of

```
node at (plant) ++$(0,1)$ (dist) {$D(s)$};
```

I can't exactly remember how to do it & I'm having trouble what keywords to even search for my problem.. So, I appreciate any kind help.

Best
Matthew

Comment: Section 13.4, 13.5 http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: The syntax `above of=plant` is depecated. Load `positioning` and use `above =<distance> of plant` instead.

Comment: Please complete your code, how are `input`, `output`, `sum` and `block` defined? Without knowing it, it's difficult to write an answer.